# Itunes "genres"

Tags: itunes

I manually changed the genres on some of my songs in my Itunes library to minimize the number of genres. I have found that after I add songs to my library and then sync them to my ipod, Itunes will change the genres back to the original listings. It never used to do this. It just started recently. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with organizing. I've been hearing cases of this recently, especially if people have custom genres that they've created. For some reason, iTunes is switching these back. Is that your case, or are these the standard genres that are in iTunes by default?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're changing the genre of a song in iTunes and not on the iOS device.

If so then maybe having iTunes organise your library is the cause (it's an option buried somewhere in the preferences)